# Laravel naming route and a href

Tags: php, laravel

```
Route::get('/products/{page?}', 'ProductController@index')->name('products');
Route::get('/products/{category}/{page?}', 'ProductController@indexCategory')->name('category.products');
```

I have two route like this.
When i call the second route like :

```
<a href="{!! route('category.products', ['category' => $category['translation']['en']['slug']]) !!}" class="list-group-item active">
```

it calls @index method instead of @indexCategory.

idk why?

I want to make

**GO TO INDEX METHOD**

> /products, /products/2, products/3

**GO TO INDEXCATEGORY METHOD**

> /products/new-collection, /products/new-collection/2,
>   /products/new-collection/3

Comment: try moving the route that has indexCategory above the index route in the handler.

Comment: The route `category.products` requires 2 parameters..You are passing only 1 parameter.

Comment: @jitheshjose second parameter is optional. If i move the indexCategory above the index route, when i send to "products/2", it wents to indexCategory method. I want to make "/products, /products/2, products/3" and also "/products/new-collection, /products/new-collection/2"

Comment: i feel like it's your naming convention and how laravel handles route requests. the optional part is causing the problem, let me check into it.

Comment: try this; 
`Route::get('/products/{category}/{page?}', 'ProductController@indexCategory')->name('products.category');`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to update the route like this.

```
Route::get('/products/{page?}', 'ProductController@index')->name('products');
Route::get('/products-category/{category}/{page?}', 'ProductController@indexCategory')->name('category.products');
```

Because naming convention conflicts your route. so make sure route URL is unique.

And then call your route like:

```
<a href="{!! route('category.products', ['category' => $category['translation']['en']['slug']]) !!}" class="list-group-item active">
```

OR

---

If you would like to do not change the route URL then make sure your second perameter required. not optional.